# Get list of queries executed in a cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

There's any way to get **all** executed queries in a cluster cassandra ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In open source Cassandra it's possible only in version 4.0 (not yet released) via Audit logging. See this [blog post about it](http://cassandra.apache.org/blog/2018/10/29/audit_logging_cassandra.html).

This functionality is also available in DataStax Enterprise - you can enable it as [described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secAuditAbout.html).

Comment: Really helpful that you covered both open source and DSE. Also, you answered about query audit logging and not tracing - so what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are asking about batch execution? You can use "SOURCE" command in cqlsh.please refer below link.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshSource.html

Comment: Thanks Pandey for your reply , what i'm looking for is to have the list of all queries executed in my cassandra cluster each day in order to analye it

Comment: Then you may enable trace level logging which will print your query in system.log.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Tracing - Either in the Cassandra configuration or you can over ride this from the client as well,

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to have Cassandra 4.0, you can also look at the ecaudit plugin from Ericsson

https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit

Setup instructions

https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit/blob/release/c3.0.11/doc/setup.md

Example output

```
2019-02-28 15:18:14.089-> client=127.0.0.1, user=cassandra, status=ATTEMPT, operation='SELECT * FROM students'
2019-02-28 15:18:14.090-> client=127.0.0.1, user=cassandra, status=ATTEMPT, batch-id=6f3cae9b-f1f1-4a4c-baa2-ed168ee79f9d, operation='INSERT INTO ecks.ectbl (partk, clustk, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)[1, '1', 'valid']'
2019-02-28 15:18:14.091-> client=127.0.0.1, user=cassandra, status=ATTEMPT, batch-id=6f3cae9b-f1f1-4a4c-baa2-ed168ee79f9d, operation='INSERT INTO ecks.ectbl (partk, clustk, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)[2, '2', 'valid']'
```